# Change Default options for TFS 2017 New Team Project in Web portal?

Tags: tfs

Is it possible to change the settingd for TFS 2017 to only have Team foundation Server version control available (disable git) and only have CMMI available for the work item process? I am using the web interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the process templates from [within Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-r/ms181510).

You can't disable Git support, but you can easily create a new TFVC repository in an existing team project if someone chooses incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not able to customize the **Create team project** process. You could not directly disable the options both for Process template and Version Control.

[image]

You could create a [uservoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services), TFS PM will kindly review your suggestion.